# JavaFX - Stop Table Column from Resizing with Parent

Tags: java, javafx

I have  table with 3 columns. The table is using a CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY.

All three columns can be resized by the user.

When the table's width increases or decreases, I would like for the middle column to stay the same width as it was (in pixels) and for the excess space be distributed (or taken) from the other columns in the same basic way that it's happening now.

Basically, I would the `SplitPane.setResizableWithParent( <child>, false )` functionality for a table column.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you can set a min and max width for the column.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson: If I do that, the user won't be able to resize the column.

Answer (score 1):

How about to reset min and max width only when the column is dragged. This is a example as a inner class.

```
class CustomResizePolicy implements Callback<TableView.ResizeFeatures, Boolean> {
    static final double DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH = 10.0F, DEFAULT_MAX_WIDTH = 5000.0F;
    @Override
    public Boolean call(TableView.ResizeFeatures feature) {
        final TableColumn<?,?> c = feature.getColumn();
        if (c == column2) {
            c.setMinWidth(DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH);
            c.setMaxWidth(DEFAULT_MAX_WIDTH);
        }
        boolean result = TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY.call(feature);
        if (c == column2) {
            c.setMinWidth(c.getWidth());
            c.setMaxWidth(c.getWidth());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(new CustomResizePolicy());
column2.setMaxWidth(200); // Need to fix column2's width in this case
column2.setMinWidth(200);
column1.setMaxWidth(5000); // Divide left margin with a ratio of 1:2
column3.setMaxWidth(10000);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the controlled column is the last column in the table. It causes the total width of the columns to be less or more than the table when the entire table is resized, and the last column to have unchangeable width. Any idea how to modify it to work in that case?

Comment: Also, the column to the left of the fixed column resizes larger improperly. (it shrinks fine).

Comment: Oh sorry... I didn't test that case and i don't have any idea for it.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me the start something to work with. I'll see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Can't you calculate the remaining width and set the last column's preferred width?

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson The calculation is complete in `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`, so I think we can't catch the remaining width.